# Упускаю из вида принципы работы КАН сети

Tags: c, сеть, сокет, can

У меня не выходит создать программу которая взаимодействуя по [CAN-Линукс протоколу](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/can.txt)  будет принимать и оправлять сообщения(именно все сообщения).

Перепробовал множество вариантов но совершенно так и не понял как иметь возможность, оправлять и принимать сообщения. Чисто отправить,  либо принять я могу, а как сделать чтоб можно было как отправить и принять (без фильтра я так  и не понял). [Вот пример котрый я видоизменил но не смог правильно настроить.](https://github.com/JCube001/socketcan-demo/blob/master/src/socketcan-bcm-demo.cpp)

**Посмотрите пожалуйста очень непонятно, что именно я упускаю из вида, из за чего и попадаю в эту "оказию"**

Вот весь код :

```
#include "util1.h"

#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

#include <linux/can.h>
#include <linux/can/bcm.h>

#define PROGNAME "socketcan-bcm-demo"
#define VERSION  "1.0.0"

#define MSGID   (0x0BC)
#define NFRAMES (1)

#define DELAY (10000)

static sig_atomic_t sigval;



static void onsig(int val)
{
    sigval = (sig_atomic_t)val;
    printf("onsig(int val)\n");
}

static void usage(void)
{
    puts("Usage: " PROGNAME "[OPTIONS] IFACE\n"
                            "Where:\n"
                            "  IFACE    CAN network interface\n"
                            "Options:\n"
                            "  -h       Display this help then exit\n"
                            "  -v       Display version info then exit\n");
}

static void version(void)
{
    puts(PROGNAME " " VERSION "\n");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // -- преднастройка н --
    int flags, opt;
    int s;
    char *iface;
    struct sockaddr_can addr;
    struct ifreq ifr;
    printf("1 !!!\n");

    struct can_msg
    {
        /**
         * struct bcm_msg_head - заголовок для сообщений в/из  менеджера сообщений (the broadcast manager)
         * @opcode:    код операции (opcodе), see enum below.
         * @flags:     специальные флаги, see below.
         * @count:     количество кадров для отправки до изменения интервала.
         * @ival1:     интервал для первых @count сообщений.
         * @ival2:     интервал для следующих кадров.
         * @can_id:    CAN ID для получения либо отправки кадров
         * @nframes:   номер кадров поднятых для присоединения к загаловку
         * @frames:    массив CAN кадров.
         */

        /**
         * struct can_frame - базовая CAN структура
         * @can_id:  идетификационный номер кан сообщения
         * @can_dlc: размерсообщения от 0 до 8 байт
         * @__pad:   "набивка :3"
         * @__res0:  "зарезервированно"
         * @__res1:  "зарезервированно"
         * @data:    само кан сообщение
         */

        struct bcm_msg_head msg_head;
        struct can_frame frame[NFRAMES];
    } msg;

    system("ip link set can0 type can bitrate 125000 ");
    printf("ip link set %s type can bitrate %d \n", "can0", 125000);
    system("ip link set can0 up");

    iface ="can0";

    // Регистация сигнальных прерывателей
    if (signal(SIGINT, onsig)    == SIG_ERR ||
            signal(SIGTERM, onsig)   == SIG_ERR ||
            signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN) == SIG_ERR)
    {
        perror(PROGNAME);
        return errno;
    }

    printf("2 !!!\n");
    // Открытие кан интерфейса
    // s = socket(PF_CAN, SOCK_RAW, CAN_RAW);
    s = socket(PF_CAN, SOCK_DGRAM, CAN_BCM);
    if (s < 0)
    {
        perror(PROGNAME ": socket \"не отработал\" ");
        return errno;
    }
    printf("2.5 !!!\n");
    strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, iface, IFNAMSIZ);
    if (ioctl(s, SIOCGIFINDEX, &ifr) < 0) // системный вызов  при извл. САНа из компа то выпрыг ошибка
    {
        perror(PROGNAME ": ioctl");
        return errno;
    }
    printf("2.8 !!!\n");
    addr.can_family = AF_CAN;
    addr.can_ifindex = ifr.ifr_ifindex;
    if (connect(s, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0)
    {
        perror(PROGNAME ": connect \"не отработал\" ");
        return errno;
    }

    printf("3 !!!\n");
    // Настройка сокета неблокирующим
    flags = fcntl(s, F_GETFL, 0);
    if (flags < 0)
    {
        perror(PROGNAME ": fcntl: F_GETFL");
        return errno;
    }

    if (fcntl(s, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK) < 0)
    {
        perror(PROGNAME ": fcntl: F_SETFL");
        return errno;
    }

    // -- преднастройка к --

    //  TX_SETUP = 1,   /* create (cyclic) transmission task */
    //  TX_DELETE,  /* remove (cyclic) transmission task */
    //  TX_READ,    /* read properties of (cyclic) transmission task */
    //  TX_SEND,    /* send one CAN frame */
    //  RX_SETUP,   /* create RX content filter subscription */
    //  RX_DELETE,  /* remove RX content filter subscription */
    //  RX_READ,    /* read properties of RX content filter subscription */
    //  TX_STATUS,  /* reply to TX_READ request */
    //  TX_EXPIRED, /* notification on performed transmissions (count=0) */
    //  RX_STATUS,  /* reply to RX_READ request */
    //  RX_TIMEOUT, /* cyclic message is absent */
    //  RX_CHANGED  /* updated CAN frame (detected content change) */
    // настраиваем сообщение
    sigval = 0;

    msg.msg_head.opcode  = RX_DELETE; //RX_READ; // RX_SETUP;
    // msg.msg_head.can_id  = 0x123;
    // msg.msg_head.flags   = 0;
    // msg.msg_head.nframes = 0;

    //    if (write(s, &msg, sizeof(msg)) < 0)
    //    {
    //        perror(PROGNAME ": write: RX_SETUP \"не отработал\" ");
    //        return errno;
    //    }

    printf("while !!!\n");
    //основной цикл
    int tex_per = 0;
    while (0 == sigval)
    {
        ssize_t nbytes;

        if(tex_per == 0)
            printf("read 5!\n");

        // Чтение из КАН интерфейса
        nbytes = read(s, &msg, sizeof(msg));
        printf("nbytes = %d \n",nbytes);
        if (nbytes < 0)
        {
            if (errno != EAGAIN)
            {
                perror(PROGNAME ": read \"не отработал\" ");
            }

            usleep(DELAY);
        }
        else if (nbytes < (ssize_t)sizeof(msg))
        {
            fputs(PROGNAME ": read: не полное BCM сообщение \n", stderr);
            usleep(DELAY);
        }
        else
        {
            struct can_frame * const frame = msg.frame;
            unsigned char * const data = frame->data;
            const unsigned int dlc = frame->can_dlc;
            unsigned int i;

            // распечатать полученный кадр
            printf("teper mit_tyty \n");  //printf("RX:   ");
            print_can_frame(frame);
            printf("TYTYTYTYT!!!!!!\n");
            printf("\n");

            // модифицируем CAN кадр, чтобы использовать наш идентификатор(ID) сообщения
            frame->can_id = MSGID;
            printf("Otpravka_1\n");
            // Увеличить значение каждого байта в кадре CAN
            for (i = 0; i < dlc; ++i)
            {
                data[i] += 1;
            }

            /* Set a TX message for sending this frame once */

            // Установить TX-сообщение для отправки "этого" кадра один раз
            msg.msg_head.opcode  = TX_SEND;
            msg.msg_head.can_id  = 8; //0
            msg.msg_head.flags   = 0;
            msg.msg_head.nframes = 1;
            printf("Otpravka_obl_2\n");
            // записать сообщение в буфер
            nbytes = write(s, &msg, sizeof(msg));
            if (nbytes < 0)
            {
                perror(PROGNAME ": write: TX_SEND непрошло сообщение");
            }
            else if (nbytes < (ssize_t)sizeof(msg))
            {
                fputs(PROGNAME ": write: неполное BCM сообщение \n", stderr);
            }
            else
            {
                // Распечатать переданный CAN кадр
                printf("TX:  ");
                print_can_frame(frame);
                printf("\n");
            }
            printf("otpravka_exit\n");
        }
        printf("KONEC!\n");
    }
    system("ip link set can0 down");
    puts("\nGoodbye!");

    // Закрытие КАН интерфейса
    if (close(s) < 0)
    {
        perror(PROGNAME ": close ошибка закрытия интерфейса ");
        return errno;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

вот `util1.c` :

```
#include "util.h"

#include <stdio.h>

void print_can_frame(const struct can_frame * const frame)
{
    const unsigned char *data = frame->data;
    const unsigned int dlc = frame->can_dlc;
    unsigned int i;

    printf("%03X  [%u] ", frame->can_id, dlc);
    for (i = 0; i < dlc; ++i)
    {
        printf(" %02X", data[i]);
    }
}
```

и `util1.h`:

```
#ifndef _UTIL_H_
#define _UTIL_H_

#include <linux/can.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void print_can_frame(const struct can_frame * const frame);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif /* _UTIL_H_ */
```

На это пример я посылаю сообщения с другого кан изделия.
[Пример который я изменил до изменений прекрастно работал как и было представленно в описании.](https://github.com/JCube001/socketcan-demo/blob/master/src/socketcan-bcm-demo.cpp)

Вот вывод : 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]